# Adicionar SOAP Header em SOAP C#

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

Estou tentando adicionar um *header* customizado em um serviço *SOAP* usando *C#*. Já procurei por tudo e não encontrei uma solução que funciona.

Estou adicionando o serviço por *Web References* do *C#*.
Já tentei fazer *override* do método *GetWebRequest*, porém ele não consegui.

O WSDL é este http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/geral/produtos/?WSDL

#### Exemplo como deve ficar

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/geral/clientes/?WSDL">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <app_key>123456789</app_key>
          <app_secret>topSecret</app_secret>
       </soapenv:Header>
   ....
```

#### Código de testes

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var servico = new omie.Produto.ProdutosCadastro();            
    servico.autenticacao = new omie.Produto.Autenticacao();
    servico.autenticacao.app_key = "123456";
    servico.autenticacao.app_secret = "123456789";

    var dados = new omie.Produto.produto_servico_list_request();
    dados.pagina = "1";
    dados.registros_por_pagina = "50";
    dados.apenas_importado_api = "N";
    dados.filtrar_apenas_omiepdv = "N";

    var produtos = servico.ListarProdutosResumido(dados);

    Console.WriteLine(produtos.total_de_registros.ToString());
}
```

O código de teste, foi uma sugestão deste post

https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/560786-how-add-soap-header-soap-message 
Procurar por texto:

> That was already described in my previous post

Além disto foi estendida a classe do SOAP com estes elementos:

```
namespace omieTestes.omie.Produto
{
    public partial class ProdutosCadastro : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
    {
        public Autenticacao autenticacao;
    }

    //[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://app.omie.com.br/autenticacao")]    
    public class Autenticacao : SoapHeader
    {
        public string app_key;
        public string app_secret;
    }
}
```

O que achei ruim é que se atualizar a referência, perde a implementação:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/geral/produtos/?WSDLListarProdutosResumido", RequestNamespace="http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/geral/produtos/?WSDL", ResponseNamespace="http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/geral/produtos/?WSDL")]
    [SoapHeader("autenticacao", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("produto_servico_list_response")]        
    public produto_servico_list_response ListarProdutosResumido(produto_servico_list_request produto_servico_list_request) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("ListarProdutosResumido", new object[] {
                    produto_servico_list_request});
        return ((produto_servico_list_response)(results[0]));
    }
```

#### Linha colocada na mão

```
[SoapHeader("autenticacao", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
```

Comment: Você pode usar o OperationContext para isso. Mostre o seu código cliente para ajudar a te mostrar como fazer.

Comment: E o seu seu arquivo de configuração cliente, a parte onde declara o `<endpoint>`

Comment: @RicardoPontual editei o post...Vê se melhorou.

Comment: Sim, ajudou, eu escrevi uma resposta com duas soluções, espero que  ajude

Comment: MarlonTiedt você está usando web reference e a resposta dada pelo @RicardoPontual utiliza ServiceReference (que utiliza as classes de WCF). WebReference está deprecated e não é aconselhado o seu uso para novos desenvolvimentos. Para fazer isto com WebReference provavelmente teria de usar WSE 3.0 e implementar um SoapFilter. No entanto o plugin de WSE não é mais suportado no Visual Studio 2015 (nas versões anteriores dá para dar a volta mas não no 2015).

Comment: @nflash é verdade, tem algumas coisas que não se pode fazer usando um proxy criado por WebReference que está obsoleto.

Comment: @nflash porém o WebReference não é para SOAP (webservice) e o ServiceReference é para serviços WCF? Existe alguma forma de não ter o binding do endpoint quando usa ServiceReference? Pois a minha aplicação é um serviço, e tem uma tela amigável e se usar ServiceReference tenho que colocar as URL nos dois app.config.

Comment: @MarlonTiedt WCF é uma framework que permite, entre outras coisas, a criação e acesso a WebServices. Suporta Soap (1.1 e 1.2), REST, TCP, MessageQueue, entre outros. O bom do WCF é que abstrai o protocolo utilizado (permitindo até ter o mesmo serviço exposto em vários protocolos utilizando vários endpoints) através da mesma API. Neste caso apenas estaria usando o proxy (cliente) gerado pela ServiceReference (este proxy extende a class ClientBase<T>). Não deverá ter problema nenhum ao utilizar este proxy para aceder a um WebService Soap. E vale a pena aprender WCF.

Answer (score 2):

Parece meio complicada essa implementação.
Eu tenho vários serviços aqui que usam valores no `Header`, vou te mostrar duas soluções que podem te atender:

**Atribuir valores no Header diretamente no Endpoint do arquivo de configuração**:
Isso é legal pois serviços que tem arquivos de configuração, não precisam ter as configuração de Header no código, a não ser que seu serviço crie o ServiceHost no código. Serviços hosteados no IIS podem enviar informações no Header apenas adicionando isso no Endpoint.

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://dominio/NomeServico.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Contrato" name="NomeConfiguracao">
    <headers>
        <app_key>123456789</app_key>
        <app_secret>topSecret</app_secret>
    </headers>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Esta é a maneira mais simples de fazer.

**Manipulando o Endpoint no código**:
Você pode manipular o `Endpoint` depois de criar o seu cliente e antes de chamar uma operação. Isso é interessante pois você pode passar valores variáveis e também que não ficam expostos no arquivo de configuração, mas tem que compilar o código:

```
ServicoWcf cliente = new ServicoWcf();
var endpointPersonalizado = new EndpointAddressBuilder(cliente.Endpoint.Address);
endpointPersonalizado.Headers.Add( AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("app_key", string.Empty, "123456789")); 
endpointPersonalizado.Headers.Add( AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("app_secret", string.Empty, "topSecret")); 
cliente.Endpoint.Address = endpointPersonalizado.ToEndpointAddress();
```

Você também pode manipular o `OperationContextScope` no cliente e adicionar o `Header`, mas eu prefiro as implementações acima. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Ricardo, como fazer quando dentro do Header tem um objeto 'Autenticar' e dentro dele temos as entradas de login e senha? Como adicionar esse objeto dentro do Header? Pelo código e não manualmente.

Comment: isso é muito estranho, pq o `header` é um dicionário do tipo <string, string>, ou seja, uma chave e um valor como está no exemplo acima, não se coloca objetos dentro do `header`, sinceramente não sei como fazer isso, e acredito que não seja possível devido a natureza do `header`

Comment: Esse é o header esperado pelo WS <soapenv:Header>
 <autenticar>
 <cnpj>xxxxxx</cnpj>
 <chave>xxxxxx</chave>
 </autenticar>
 </soapenv:Header>.

Comment: ah, adicionar um soap header é outra coisa. Tem algumas maneira de fazer isso, mas se está usando .NET, pode adicionar o header no seu contrato com o atributo `[MessageHeader]`

Comment: pra dar um norte, suponha que seu contrato é a classe "Contrato", o a classe que quer adicionar no soap header é "Autenticar". Pode usar assim:
`[DataContract]public class Contrato { [MessageHeader]public Contrato contrato {get; set; } ..`

Comment: Isso mesmo. Inclusive fiz uma pergunta aqui no site sobre isso e um colega me ajudou. Te agradeço também pela explicação e ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
  ProdutoCadastroService.ProdutosCadastroSoapClient produtoCadastroWS = new    ProdutoCadastroService.ProdutosCadastroSoapClient();
  autenticaWsHeader(produtoCadastroWS);

  private static void autenticaWsHeader(ProdutosCadastroSoapClient produtoCadastroWS)
  {
        new OperationContextScope(produtoCadastroWS.InnerChannel);

        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessage.Headers["Username"] = "admin";
        requestMessage.Headers["Password"] = "123";
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

using (Endpoint1WS.MeuObjectClient proxy = new Endpoint1WS.MeuObjectClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMeuObject1"))
            {
                using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
                {
                    MessageHeader head = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("app_hey", "https://meuenderecoNamespace/", "123456");
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(head);
                    var fatura = proxy.ObterAlgo();

```
            }
        }
```