# Adicionar SOAP Header customizável

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-core, soap

Estou consumindo um *web service SOAP* que não disponibiliza nenhuma informação dos `Headers`, nem de `autenticação`.

Adicionei o mesmo no meu projeto pela ferramenta **Add Connected Service** no Visual Studio.

Procurando um pouco aqui pelo site, encontrei esse tópico: [Adicionar SOAP Header em SOAP C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158522/adicionar-soap-header-em-soap-c/158768?noredirect=1#comment853694_158768)

Que me ajudou a criar um `Header` e adicionar com sucesso no meu `client`:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddressBuilder(client.Endpoint.Address);                
                endpoint.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("cnpj", string.Empty, "xxxxxxxx"));
                endpoint.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("chave", string.Empty, "xxxxxxxx"));

client.Endpoint.Address = endpoint.ToEndpointAddress();
```

Contudo, o `Header` esperado pelo *web service* é diferente do comum:

```
 <soapenv:Header>
     <Autenticar>
         <cnpj>xxxxxxx</cnpj>
         <chave>xxxxxxx</chave>
     </Autenticar>
 </soapenv:Header>
```

Possui um objeto `<Autenticar>` dentro do `Header`.

Já tentei esse tópico também [Adding SOAP implicit headers to WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726127/adding-soap-implicit-headers-to-wsdl), contudo, sem sucesso.

Como consigo adicionar esse `<Autenticar>` dentro do meu `Header`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma classe que identifique o objeto que quer enviar no header.

Exemplo:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class autenticar
{
    [DataMember]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string chave { get; set; }
}
```

Depois, encapsule seu cliente em um escopo e adicione seu objetos ao cabeçalho da mensagem:

```
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    var autenticar = new autenticar() { chave = "minha chave", cnpj = "meu cnpj" };
    var autenticarHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("autenticar", string.Empty, autenticar);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(autenticarHeader);

    //Aqui você consume o webservice
}
```

O resultado será este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem palavras, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: De nada @perozzo.